# bash command timeout, redirect kill messages to null

Tags: bash

```
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 3; kill $cmdpid) & exec ./myscript )
```

This is working but I don't know how to supress kill messages

```
line 80: 30631 Terminated              
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; ( sleep 3; kill $cmdpid 2> /dev/null 0<&1 2>&1 ) & exec .....
```

I tried to redirect but no success. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I resolved myself in other way and I'd like to share... maybe someone will need in future.
This will allow ./script to execute with timeout and capture it's output including errors.

The minor drawback which I couldn't solve was to signal the main $shell if any events occured (like timeout or other error) in any other way than appending that results to $OUT with echo. I guess this is the most stupid part in bash programming (among most others), each () construct in it's own pid and isolate variables. Anyhow, please enjoy.

```
OUT=$((./script) & pid=$!
    # will exit 128 + (signal number)

    (sleep $RUN_TIMEOUT && kill -HUP $pid) 2>/dev/null & watcher=$!  

    if wait $pid; status=$?; then
        if [[ $status -eq 129 ]]; then # 129 -> OK (hangup, means timeout)
            echo "execution_timeout"
        else
            # other, including 255 -> return error
            echo "execution_error"

        fi
    fi # 0 -> normal return, success

    pkill -HUP -P $watcher    
    wait $watcher    

) 2>&1 # + stderr
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is apparently coming from the job control feature of the shell. Disabling it in the *parent* shell seems to work:

```
set +m
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 3; kill $cmdpid) & exec ./myscript )
```

---

The message isn't coming from `kill`, but rather the background subshell which executes the `kill`. Try

```
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 3; kill $cmdpid) 2> /dev/null & exec ./myscript )
```

Other attempts:

```
( set +m; cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 3; kill $cmdpid) & sleep 5 )
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 3; kill $cmdpid); disown %%  & sleep 5 )
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 3; kill $cmdpid); disown %1  & sleep 5 )
```

(I used `sleep 5` as a stand-in for the exec. The only apparent difference is that I see just the word "Terminated" as notification.)

Comment: Hm, I was testing in `bash` 3, which doesn't set `BASHPID` and so the `kill` wasn't running. Testing in `bash` 4, it seems that the shell is writing the line directly to the terminal. I tried using `disown` on the background process, as well as disabling job control with `set +m`, with no success.

Comment: I've done some further debug... the "Terminated" message is referring to $BASHPID pid and is thrown by kill, since when I use kill -HUP the message is changed to "Hangup....". But there is no way to suppress ?!

Comment: See my edit; I'll clean out the failed attempts if that works.

Comment: set +m has nothing effect. However, I'll give you credits for your effort, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution (depending upon your platform) may be to use the `timeout` command.

```
$ /usr/bin/timeout 30 /path/to/exec
```

This will stop the process `/path/to/exec` after 30 seconds.

If I use `timeout 2>/dev/null 1 sleep 2`, I get a 'Killed' response. Which is probably the same as where you are at with your method...

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux with the command timeout available it can be achieved as follows:

```
timeout --foreground <time in seconds> <command>
```

As from the man page:

```
       --foreground

          when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,

          allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals; in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
```

It also suppresses the "Terminated"/"Killed" message.